# Build ThingsBoard Server UI Could not extract the Yarn archive

Tags: angularjs, yarnpkg, thingsboard

I try to build github project ThingsBoard from source,when it comes to the **Server UI ** part.there comes a error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-yarn (install node and npm) on project ui-ngx: Could not extract the Yarn archive: Could not rename versioned yarn root directory to dist.
could anyone tell me why? I googled and find nothing about this error.Thks

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ui-ngx ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\IIOT\thingsboard\ui-ngx\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-yarn (install node and npm) @ ui-ngx ---
[INFO] Installing node version v18.16.0
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\AlexFu\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\18.16.0\node-18.16.0-win-x64.exe to E:\IIOT\thingsboard\ui-ngx\target\node\node.exe
[INFO] Installed node locally.
[INFO] Installing Yarn version v1.22.19
[INFO] Unpacking C:\Users\AlexFu\.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\yarn\1.22.19\yarn-1.22.19.tar.gz into E:\IIOT\thingsboard\ui-ngx\target\node\yarn
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Thingsboard 3.5.1:
[INFO]
[INFO] Thingsboard ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.047 s]
[INFO] Netty MQTT Client .................................. SUCCESS [  1.900 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Commons ......................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Data ..................... SUCCESS [  4.682 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Utils .................... SUCCESS [  0.692 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Messages ................. SUCCESS [  1.715 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Actor system ........................... SUCCESS [  0.882 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Stats ........................... SUCCESS [  0.296 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Cluster API .............. SUCCESS [  6.486 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Queue components ................ SUCCESS [  2.011 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Cache .................... SUCCESS [  0.717 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Commons ......................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Transport components ..... SUCCESS [  2.392 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard MQTT Transport Common .................. SUCCESS [  2.362 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard HTTP Transport Common .................. SUCCESS [  0.541 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard CoAP server ............................ SUCCESS [  0.523 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard CoAP Transport Common .................. SUCCESS [  1.449 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard LwM2M Transport Common ................. SUCCESS [  1.412 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard SNMP Transport Common .................. SUCCESS [  1.026 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common DAO API .................. SUCCESS [  0.782 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Remote Edge wrapper ............. SUCCESS [  2.683 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Version Control API ............. SUCCESS [  0.629 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Script Invoke Commons .................. SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Script invoke API ............... SUCCESS [  0.784 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Extensions ............................. SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Rule Engine API ........................ SUCCESS [  0.937 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server JS Client for remote JS execution SUCCESS [  1.202 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server DAO Layer ....................... SUCCESS [  4.855 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Rule Engine Components ................. SUCCESS [  3.681 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Transport Modules ............... SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard HTTP Transport Service ................. SUCCESS [ 15.605 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard MQTT Transport Service ................. SUCCESS [ 12.030 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard CoAP Transport Service ................. SUCCESS [ 11.370 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard LwM2m Transport Service ................ SUCCESS [ 14.500 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard SNMP Transport Service ................. SUCCESS [ 11.576 s]
[INFO] ThingsBoard Server UI .............................. FAILURE [  0.117 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Tools ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Thingsboard Rest Client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Server Application ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Microservices .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Docker Images .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Web UI Microservice .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Version Control Executor ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Version Control Executor Microservice .. SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Node Microservice ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Transport Microservices ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard MQTT Transport Microservice ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard HTTP Transport Microservice ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard COAP Transport Microservice ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard LWM2M Transport Microservice ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard SNMP Transport Microservice ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard JavaScript Executor Microservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Monitoring Service ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Monitoring Microservice ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-12T16:40:17+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-yarn (install node and npm) on project ui-ngx: Could not extract the Yarn archive: Could not rename versioned yarn root directory to dist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ui-ngx
```

I tried to download the yarn.and put it in the dir.it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the generated target directory and replace yarn & node repo url and then rebuild it.
Here I use huawei repo to download yarn and nodejs.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v16.15.1</nodeVersion>
                        <yarnVersion>v1.22.17</yarnVersion>
                        <nodeDownloadRoot>http://repo.huaweicloud.com/nodejs/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                        <yarnDownloadRoot>http://repo.huaweicloud.com/yarn/</yarnDownloadRoot>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).